# Containment Anxiety

Tags: dogs, containment, anxiety

I have a male mini Daschsund who has what I have identified as severe containment anxiety which he has had since the age of 10 weeks when I brought him home. It was originally misdiagnosed as separation anxiety which often happens- as he has increased with age ( he is now 9) so has his containment anxiety- I have tried the thunder shirt, pheromones and he is now on 10 mg Prozac once daily which does help calm him enough that he no longer self harms, as a Daschsund he must be contained at night and when we are gone (due to IVDD risks) 
My immediate need is to find a way to contain him that he can't escape from but that is sturdy enough to contain him that he cant knock over or chew his way out of.
I can't leave him in a room of my home like a gated kitchen or bathroom because he has and will chew himself out (trim and door frames) 
There are no doggie daycares in my rural area and that wouldn't fix the bedtime/overnight issue anyway

Please Help